# How to create UNIQUE key in mysql with BLANK value?

Tags: mysql

I have a `mysql` table `users`.

A column named `Email` contains `NULL` value.

I'm not able to create a `unique` key on `email`. It is showing an error saying `duplicate value ''`.

Comment: What storage engine does the table use? [According to docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html), BDB doesn't allow multiple nulls in a unique index, but other engines do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have multiple records on the email column with the value empty: `''`

If you use InnoDB you can have multiple `NULL` values, but you can not have multiple empty values `''`.

Try to clean the empty values with `UPDATE users SET email = NULL WHERE email = ''` and then create the unique key.